# tmux completion (not shell completion)

Tags: shell, tmux, tab-completion

Is there any way to do completion of arbitrary text from your `tmux` session (e.g. output from previous commands)? Something similar to [`hippie-expand`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand) in `emacs` or [Any word completion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Any_word_completion) in `vim`? Note that I'm not looking for completion through my shell but rather through `tmux` itself.

For example, if I just started a fresh `tmux` session and did:

```
$ some_command
output line 1
output line 2 hippopotamus

$ hippop<ctl-b : hippie-expand>
```

I would like the word hippopotamus to be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing I have found: https://tmux.reconquest.io

I tried it. Basically you bind a key to their autocompletion. When you invoke that key, it will use the (part of) the word behind your cursor to find a list of candidate completions. You choose from those completions.